# Clearing Mapkit Data

Tags: mapkit

I'm running the Mapkit with GPS. The google maps pictures begin to load up. I leave to another part of the program. When I come back to the GPS, it no longer loads the pictures from google maps. For memory saving reasons, I'd like to clear that data so when I come back to the gps, it loads the pictures again. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I would destroy the map view controller instance.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, clear your unused objects and recreate your map view.